# Sobre o iframe do HTML

Tags: html, iframe

Olá gente? Então é uma dúvida simples que quero saber sobre o iframe no html, Queria saber se o iframe guarda os sites no cache?

Motivo: meu site é estatico e quero usar iframe pra deixar um pouco dinamico.

Comment: O controle de cache não é feito pelas "tags" como IFRAME é feito pelo que o HTTP de resposta especificar e pelo o que o navegador do usuário decidir manter

Answer (score 2):

O controle de cache não é feito pelas "tags" como IFRAME e não é resolvido no front-end, é feito pelo que o HTTP de resposta especificar e pelo o que o navegador do usuário decidir manter, não irá diferenciar acesso via IFRAME ou direto, a não ser detectando o cabeçalho HTTP `Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe` que envia a instrução, e isso só será útil se o site que recebe a **requisição HTTP** for dinâmico e entender que ao receber algo como:

```
GET /iframe.html HTTP/2
Host: foo.bar
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://foo.bar/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
```

Isso acima é o que o seu navegador envia para o site para solicitar a página dentro do IFRAME, então se o servidor tiver implementado algo para detectar o `Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe` e dizer nesse caso que não deve fazer cache ou fazer.

Agora entenda que isso só vai funcionar se você programar do lado do servidor, mas o "normal" (em caso de páginas estáticas) é **fazer ou não** cache de uma página baseado apenas nos headers devolvidos pelo back-end e que nada terá haver com o IFRAME.